# Backsliding (Parliamentary v. Presidential)

Tags: president, comparative-politics, parliament

Is a parliamentary system less likely to backslide into electoral authoritarianism than a presidential system just because of the PM being accountable to the legislature and the ease of a no confidence vote compared to impeachment?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer this question, but I know one relevant example: Erdogan has recently moved Turkey from a parliamentary to a presidential executive in order to cement his power. I take that to indicate that he felt being president was better than being PM for an authoritarian leader.

Comment: Hitler came to power in a parliamentary system but became President as well as Chancellor following a 1934 referendum. I'm not sure if this supports or opposes the OP's conjecture. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_referendum,_1934

Comment: @StuartF Rather a “referendum” than a referendum.  There was widespread intimidation and fraud, and cannot be considered as democratic.  By the time of the “referendum”, the backsliding had already happened.

Comment: Does this question fit better on [History.SE]?

Comment: @gerrit as asked, I don't think this question fits better on [History.SE].  It's a theoretical question; historical evidence may be useful for considering different hypotheses, but the question itself is fairly abstract.

Comment: This is a good question, but I think in the end this would be opinion-based and may very by cultural and/or systemic context.